# What security rules should be added to Google Cloud Firestore to keep data safe where no authentication is required to access the app

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an android app which is using Firestore as database. I need to make it secure but I am not using authentication service as it is not required.

I was thinking if I can sent a unique ID from android app which can be recognised in Firestore rules and only users(people using my app) can read or write to Firestore.

Below is my security rules -

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow readwrite ;
    }
  }
}
```

I expect my Firestore database to be safe from non-users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was thinking if I can sent a unique ID

You can't pass arbitrary values to security rules. To send that securely and get it into the security rules, you will have to pass it into the user's authentication token as a custom claim.

But even if you do that, what will keep a malicious user from finding that same secret values (it must be available in your app after all), and passing it into the security rules in the same way.

Coming to think of it, anonymous authentication and custom claims may be your solution. Use [anonymous authentication on the client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) to generate a UID for the user, then (on a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions) [give that user a custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims), and [check for that custom claim in your security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth).